# TypeError when replacing strings with a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My code is pretty simple:

```
['found' if 'some_string' in word else word for word in wordlist]
```

But it returns

```
    TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-108-990cad51d935> in <module>()
    ----> 1 [word  for word in wordlist if 'some_string' in word ]

    <ipython-input-108-990cad51d935> in <listcomp>(.0)
    ----> 1 [word  for word in wordlist if 'some_string' in word ]

    TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

(I've tried rearranging it in several ways to no avail.)

By comparison, this code does exactly as expected:

```
for word in wordlist:
    if 'some_string' in word:
        print ('found')
    else:
        print(word)
```

All I want is to replace the any string that contains 'some_string' with 'found'.

Further context: wordlist is the values from a column of a Pandas dataframe in a Jupyter notebook.

```
wordlist = list(df.sender.values)
type(wordlist)
 list
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: how does `wordlist` look like? [Cannot reproduce.](https://repl.it/repls/DisfiguredMemorableStructs)

Comment: Try setting `wordlist=["some_string1", "some_other'string"]`, and then try your list comprehension.

Comment: are you maybe doing something like `wordlist = wordlist.append('new_text')` further up?

Comment: your worldlist will be not proper as per the error is given... better use this `str.replace(old, new[, max])` to replace word in string...

Comment: @DanielRoseman I edited the question to include the traceback

Comment: My list may contain non-unicode text, could that be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might solve this by simply using "str()" to enable the comparison with values recovered from the list.

Here is an example that demonstrates this:

```
wordlist = ['some_string', 'sometext', 'some_string', 'randomtext', None]
['found' if 'some_string' in str(word) else word for word in wordlist]
```

The output is

```
['found', 'sometext', 'found', 'randomtext', None]
```

(To produce the error, inside the comprehension replace str(word), with word.)

Comment: Great, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You have `None` values in your wordlist.
Upon encountering the first of them it throws the error.
Python is unable to iterate over `None` type, but it needs to start iteration in order to find out if a string is contained in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Change your list comprehension to :

```
output = ['found' if (word and 'some_string' in word) else word for word in wordlist]
```

The key point here is `if word`. The issue is there are some `None` elements in your dataframe and that is affecting the iteration.
I do not think this has anything to do with unicode elements